# Error when apply 'apply' function to 'modularity' function

Tags: r, apply, modularity, igraph

Today I fail to apply `apply` function to `modularity` function, where the latter function is in the 'igraph' package. Followings are the codes and results"

```
> library(igraph)
> g = graph.full(2)
> modularity(g, 1:2)
[1] -0.5
> apply(FUN = modularity, MARGIN = 1, X = matrix(1:4, ncol = 2), graph = g, weights = NULL)
Error in UseMethod("modularity") : 
no applicable method for 'modularity' applied to an object of class "c('integer',     'numeric')"
```

I was able to use the `apply` and `modularity` function in this way and no error messages came out yesterday. But today R throws the error message above. Have anyone met this problem? Please tell me how to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change **graph** name to **x** should work. Here I also reorder the terms, but it is optional.

```
apply(X = matrix(1:4, ncol = 2) , MARGIN = 1,FUN = modularity, x = g, weights = NULL)
1] -0.5 -0.5
```

You get an error because modularity don't find its x argument so try to apply it to the column matrix given by `apply`.